# How to call a return statement from another method in Java?

Tags: java, return

I have an event handler for the user hitting the enter key, and I need that to return a value from another method. Essentially, if you have `return "hi";` in method b, and the Event Handler in method A, I need a line of code to return "hi". (note, in the code, "hi" would vary). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish; it sounds like you know what you want to happen but you're not familiar with the exact terminology.

Comment: To run something in another method you need to call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call your method in the `return` statement

```
public int method1() {
    return method2(); //return the return value of method2
}

public int method2() {
    return 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I think you can use `Thread.interrupted()`. Something like this:

```
public class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
    private Thread otherThread;

    public KeyHandler(Thread otherThread) {
        this.otherThread = otherThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) otherThread.interrupt();
    }
}

public class OtherClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        while(!Thread.isInterrupted()) {
            // dosomething
        }
        return;
    }
}
```